# Flutter web Http GET throws unwaited function

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm running an HTTP get using flutter for the web and after connecting it stops running and directs me to the browser_client.dart file highlighting this function

```
 unawaited(xhr.onLoad.first.then((_) {
  var body = (xhr.response as ByteBuffer).asUint8List();
  completer.complete(StreamedResponse(
      ByteStream.fromBytes(body), xhr.status!,
      contentLength: body.length,
      request: request,
      headers: xhr.responseHeaders,
      reasonPhrase: xhr.statusText));
}));
```

then afterward shows this on the debug console

```
Error: error
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:53840/dart_sdk.js:5061:11)
at searchListing (http://localhost:53840/packages/maimo/app/data/services/api.dart.lib.js:33:19)
    at searchListing.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:53840/dart_sdk.js:38640:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:53840/dart_sdk.js:38511:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:53840/dart_sdk.js:33713:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:53840/dart_sdk.js:34265:49)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to down-graded the http package in pubspec.yaml. in my case, I was down-graded to ^0.13.5 version. with this step was solved in my case